# Paths with least elevation gain

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I have a DEM of a city with numerous hills and a shapefile of the city streets. I want to find the five paths from a low point A to a high point B on the street network that involve the least elevation gain, that is, that have the fewest sections of downhill. Is it possible using QGIS/GRASS?

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me.  It seems ALL paths from A to B will have the same net elevation gain.  Perhaps you need to specify what you mean by "fewest sections of downhill".  I guess that sounds to me like you'd like to "stay level as often as possible; when I hit a hill I want it to be steep but short (in length)".  Is that it?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: What I mean is, for all routes I go uphill and then downhill because the city has hills. However, depending on which way I go there are more hills so I end up going uphill and downhill more. Ideally the best route is one which just goes uphill until I get to my destination. Can I use the DEM and the street network to plot five paths where i will go downhill the least amount (therefore least amount uphill in total)?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using raster based analysis with [r.walk](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/r.walk.html) in GRASS GIS. An example on North Carolina sample dataset:

```
g.region raster=elevation@PERMANENT
v.to.rast -d input=streets_wake@PERMANENT output=streets_wake use=val
r.mapcalc "friction = if (isnull(streets_wake), 100000, 0)"
r.walk -k elevation=elevation@PERMANENT friction=friction output=walk_cost outdir=walk_dir start_coordinates=641865,226184 walk_coeff=0,1,0,0 slope_factor=0 --o
r.drain -d input=walk_cost direction=walk_dir output=drain drain=drain start_coordinates=643392,226324 -n --o
```

r.walk computes time (cumulative cost) to walk from A to B based on slope and friction (type of surface) using cost analysis. If we change the walk_coeff a, b, c, d so that the cost increases only when going uphill, we should get the desired behavior. Friction is here used to basically mask out cells which don't represent streets, that's why I put high number there.

I am not sure how to effectively find the next best path.